# Using React + Firebase, how to modify state inside a nested query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently initialize my state like this:

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        conversations: {},
        messages: {},
        availableConversations: {}
    }
},
```

If I do something like:

```
convosRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        this.setState({ conversations: snapshot.val() });
    });
```

It works as desired... however:

```
users: {
    uid: {
        conversations: {
            conversationid: true,
            conversationid2: true
        }
    }
}
```

I successfully get the desired object:

```
userSnapshot.child('conversations').forEach(function (conversationKey) {
            var conversationRef = database.ref('conversations').child(conversationKey.key);
            conversationRef.on('value', function (conversationsSnapshot) {
                var conversation = conversationsSnapshot.val();
                conversationLoadedCount = conversationLoadedCount + 1;
                myObject[conversationKey.key] = conversation;
                // console.log(conversationKey.key);
                //this.state.conversations = conversation;

                if (conversationLoadedCount === conversationCount) {
                    console.log("We've loaded all conversations");

                }
            });
            this.setState({ conversations: myObject });
        });
    });
```

However. I receive two errors and I can't affect the state:
First error:
`FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null``

And slightly similar:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null`

I based my code on this excellent answer with no success whatsoever:
[Firebase two-way relationships / Retrieving data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682558/firebase-two-way-relationships-retrieving-data?rq=1)

This is running inside the `componentDidMount function`.

Any suggestions on how to affect the state?

Comment: I found the solution to my problem. Just adding ".bind(this)" after each firebase call did the trick. I don't want to mark it as an answer because I could use some advice about performance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES6 if you use the fat arrow function this would be much cleaner and "this" would be bound, For example:

```
   userSnapshot.child('conversations').forEach((conversationKey) => {
            var conversationRef = database.ref('conversations').child(conversationKey.key);
            conversationRef.on('value', (conversationsSnapshot) => {
```

Comment: This is the kind of insight I was looking for. Where can I read more about this? Why this "fat arrow" function binds automatically?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem just by trying to bind it.
The solution is to use `bind(this)` whenever I do a call on the `firebase.database().ref()`.
Here is the final snippet, hope it helps a poor soul like me and if someone has a better answer or some explanation on how to improve this please let me know:

var myObject = {};
        usersRef.on('value', function (userSnapshot) {

```
        // First we get the qty of conversations.
        var conversationCount = userSnapshot.child('conversations').numChildren();
        // we initialize an empty counter
        var conversationLoadedCount = 0;
        // we traverse now the conversations ref with the past conversations.
        userSnapshot.child('conversations').forEach(function (conversationKey) {
            var conversationRef = database.ref('conversations').child(conversationKey.key);
            conversationRef.on('value', function (conversationsSnapshot) {
                var conversation = conversationsSnapshot.val();

                conversationLoadedCount = conversationLoadedCount + 1;
                myObject[conversationKey.key] = conversation;
                // console.log(conversationKey.key);
                this.state.conversations[conversationKey.key] = conversation;
                this.setState({ conversations: this.state.conversations });
                if (conversationLoadedCount === conversationCount) {
                    console.log("We've loaded all conversations");
                }
            }.bind(this)); // one for the usersRef
        }.bind(this)); // another one for the forEach inside 
    }.bind(this)); // the final one for the conversationRef.on...
```